# Q:Apple Script:How to get IP address

Tags: applescript

I have been trying to make Apple Script check if the computer is connected to the internet by getting its IPv4 address. I have tried the following:

1. `tell application "system events" get IPv4 address`
2. `system info IPv4 address`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You did say "... check if the computer is connected to the internet.", it that all you're trying to do? Are you trying to get you local IPv4 address or your Internet IPv4 address, (if your ISP is assigning  one an not just an IPv6 address)? Or are you just trying to see if you're connected to the Internet? What exactly do you want?

Comment: It just needs to get the IP address, I don't actually need the IP address but I thought I could do: `on error display notification "communication services are down" with title ALERT`  and if it successfully gets the IP then I could do `display notification "Communication services still work" with title "ALERT" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out… this should work for you

```
try
    set theIP to do shell script "curl ifconfig.co"

    set the clipboard to theIP

    activate
    display dialog "Your Current IP Address Is.." & linefeed & theIP & linefeed ¬
        & "It Has Been Copied To Your Clipboard" with icon 2 buttons ¬
        "OK" default button 1 with title "Your Current IP Address Is.." giving up after 10
on error 
    display dialog "You Have No Internet Connection" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK"
end try
```

[image]

Comment: My clipboard got set to **`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Application Error</title>
<style media="screen">
        html,body,iframe {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
        html,body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
        iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0;
        }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>  </body>
</html>`**

Comment: That’s odd… I just ran that code using my normal ip address assigned by my service provider and also while using a VPN with a different ip address.  On my end, I have not been able to duplicate your error.

Comment: t just needs to get the IP address, I don't actually need the IP address but I thought I could do: `on error display notification "communication services are down" with title ALERT` and if it successfully gets the IP then I could do `display notification "Communication services still work" with title "ALERT"`

Answer (score 1):

I modified script to support IPv6. Try this out…

```
try
    set theIP to do shell script "curl --ipv4 https://ifconfig.co"
    set theIP6 to do shell script "curl --ipv6 https://ifconfig.co"
    activate
    display dialog "Your IP Addres Is  " & theIP & linefeed & theIP6 & linefeed with icon 2 buttons ¬
        "OK" default button 1 with title "Your Current IP Address Is.." giving up after 10
    
on error number error_number
    if error_number = 7 then
        set theIP to do shell script "curl --ipv4 https://ifconfig.co"
        display dialog "Your IP Addres Is  " & theIP & linefeed with icon 2 buttons ¬
            "OK" default button 1 with title "Your Current IP Address Is.." giving up after 10
    else
        display dialog "You Have No Internet Connection" buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" giving up after 3
    end if
end try
```